# API NodeJS Express and Firebase for React native

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, react-native

I developed an API (node ​​js, express and firebase) to consume it in my native app react Voila the structure of my API:
API: Allows you to select a number of users who respect a certain conditions and after calling a function that allows to modify fields in my database firebase: API works very well when I test it on browser.

Here is the structure of my API:

```
    router.get ('/: senderID /: numberOfShare /: drop', function (req, res, next) { 
      // Code that allows users to be selected from the database FOREACH {
         // call to a function (function2) which allows to modify the data of users in the BDD
   }
    // define the function2 here { modify user data in the database
   } 
  }
```

My question is: how can I exploit my API properly from my react-native app?

I did a test but did not work.

Test:

```
shareDrop (drop, parent) {
   fetch ('192.168.1.4:3000/users/senderID/numberOfShare/drop',
    { method: 'GET', 
    headers: { 
      Accept: 'application / json', 
      'Content-Type': 'application / json', 
    } 
    params: JSON.stringify
     ({ 
       senderID: this.state.uid,
        numberOfShare: 'parent.state.numberOfShare',
        drop: drop 
      }), 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `info.plist` allows for localhost or other APIs to communicate with it.

#### Info.plist

```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
```

[Here](https://github.com/richTheCreator/RN_GUARD) is a repo I've built that demonstrates how a `react-native` app can communicate with a `node` server and a `mongo` database. Maybe you can find some inspiration there.

Comment: Okey, Thank you for your comment